# How to change DNS settings to redirect website.com to www.website.com?

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname

I have a DNS linked to Sites using `CNAME` from `www` in my DNS settings below. So when i type `www.website.com` it redirects me properly but when I type `website.com` nothing happens. I am thinking about editing `@` to add something to redirect to the `www` but I am not sure how to do that. Cold you please help me out?

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the web server your utilizing, but what your looking for is url redirects. You can put in different urls and have the redirect to the primary. So you would place your domain.com in here to redirect to your binded url which is the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com). should also be able to use it to redirect http to https, though this is usually less of an issue with browsers and servers today.